# Does Sim City 4 'blow up' at any point?

Tags: simcity-4

## Please keep all answers spoiler free. Thank you.

In Sim City 2000, once you reached a point of virtual city utopia, **something happened**.

> You gained the arcologies that housed millions of people each.

This gave you something else to do, and prevented the game from stagnating. Does anything like this happen in Sim City 4?

Please format your answer with a simple yes or no, and put what happens (if applicable) in a spoiler format using > followed by !.

Comment: @Kip You realize you just took what I put into my spoiler and posted it visibly right? That defeats the purpose of the spoiler. And yes, thats what I mean. I had forgotten what they were called.

Comment: well there's no way to do a spoiler in comments. the comment is deleted now. (but is a type of building that was in the manual in a nineteen-year-old game really a spoiler anyway?)

Comment: @Kip omg nineteen years? it's been that long? I feel so old. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, to answer your question title, there are disasters so things can literally blow up!

Unlike Simcity 2000, when your city has peaked you are encouraged to start a new one and link them together, covering the region's land mass with interconnected towns/cities.

Comment: so other than the personal satisfaction of creating a wealthy successfull city, I get nothing for 'beating the game?'

Comment: Well, at least it's pretty satisfying! You can set your own meta challenges up, such as creating a city next door to take all of the rubbish from the big one, or build another megacity next door and try to lure the inhabitants from your established city away...